# configuring nutch regex-normalize.xml

Tags: java, lucene, search-engine, nutch, web-crawler

I am using the Java-based Nutch web-search software. In order to prevent duplicate (url) results from being returned in my search query results, I am trying to remove (a.k.a. normalize) the expressions of 'jsessionid' from the urls being indexed when running the Nutch crawler to index my intranet. However my modifications to $NUTCH_HOME/conf/regex-normalize.xml (prior to running my crawl) do not seem to be having any effect.

1. How can I ensure that my regex-normalize.xml configuration is being engaged for my crawl? and,
2. What regular expression will successfully remove/normalize expressions of 'jsessionid' from the url during the crawl/indexing?

The following is the contents of my current regex-normalize.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<regex-normalize>
<regex>
 <pattern>(.*);jsessionid=(.*)$</pattern>
 <substitution>$1</substitution>
</regex>
<regex>
 <pattern>(.*);jsessionid=(.*)(\&amp;|\&amp;amp;)</pattern>
 <substitution>$1$3</substitution>
</regex>
<regex>
 <pattern>;jsessionid=(.*)</pattern>
 <substitution></substitution>
</regex>
</regex-normalize>
```

Here is the command that I am issuing to run my (test) 'crawl':

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir /tmp/test/crawl_test -depth 3 -topN 500
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Nutch are you using? I'm not familiar with Nutch but the default download of Nutch 1.0 already contains a rule in *regex-normalize.xml* which seems to handle this problem.

```
<!-- removes session ids from urls (such as jsessionid and PHPSESSID) -->
<regex>
  <pattern>([;_]?((?i)l|j|bv_)?((?i)sid|phpsessid|sessionid)=.*?)(\?|&amp;|#|$)</pattern>
  <substitution>$4</substitution>
</regex>
```

Btw. *regex-urlfilter.txt* seems to contain something of relevance too

```
# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
-[?*!@=]
```

Then there are some settings in *nutch-default.xml* which you might want to check out

```
urlnormalizer.order
urlnormalizer.regex.file
plugin.includes
```

If that all doesn't help maybe this does: [How can I force fetcher to use custom nutch-config?](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/FAQ#How_can_I_force_fetcher_to_use_custom_nutch-config.3F)

Comment: I am using Nutch version 0.8.1.

This version has the following setting in nutch-default.xml:

urlnormalizer.class

...instead of 

urlnormalizer.order

I changed the value from org.apache.nutch.net.BasicUrlNormalizer to org.apache.nutch.net.RegexUrlNormalizer.

This is what causes the regex-normalize.xml file to actually be engaged when crawling.

Also, I added the following plugin to the 'plugin-includes' value:

urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)

This is not included by default in version 0.8.1.

Thanks soo much for pointing me in the right direction!