# Adding URL parameter to Nutch/Solr index and search results

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I can't find any hint on how to setup nutch to NOT filter/remove my URL parameters. I want to crawl and index some pages where lots of content is hidden behind the same base URLs (like */news.jsp?id=1 /news.jsp?id=2 /news.jsp?id=3* and so on).

- the **regex-normalize.xml** only removes redundant stuff from the URL (like session id, and trailing ?)
- the **regex-urlfilter.txt** seems to have a wildcard for my host *(+^http://$myHost/)*

The crawling works fine so far. Any ideas?

cheers,
mana

EDIT:

A part of the solution is hidden here:

[configuring nutch regex-normalize.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751597/configuring-nutch-regex-normalize-xml)

```
# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
-[?*!@=]
```

has to be modfied. One has to allow all chars that may exist in a URL parameter like '?' and '='. The new line looks like

```
-[*!@]
```

And pages are crawled now with params. But they are not yet send to Solr with parameters (Solr still cuts the parameters from the links)

EDIT2:

Nutch has some issues on how to handle relative urls ('?param=value'). Still stuck on that Parameter thing:

see maling list: http://search.lucidimagination.com/search/document/b6011a942b323ba3/problem_with_href_param_value_links

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom field in a Nutch filter to save the entire URL. As long as you define the same field in the Solr schema with store="true" it will show up in your results. See [WritingPluginExample-1.2](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample-1.2).

Let me know if you'd like some help.