# Nutch 1.2 - Why won't nutch crawl url with query strings?

Tags: nutch

I'm new to Nutch and not really sure what is going on here.  I run nutch and it crawl my website, but it seems to ignore URLs that contain query strings.  I've commented out the filter in the crawl-urlfilter.txt page so it look like this now:

```
# skip urls with these characters
#-[]

#skip urls with slash delimited segment that repeats 3+ times
#-.*(/[^/]+)/[^/]+\1/[^/]+\1/
```

So, i think i've effectively removed any filter so I'm telling nutch to accept all urls it finds on my website.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Or is this a bug in nutch 1.2? Should i upgrade to 1.3 and will this fix this issue i am having?  OR am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nutch 1.9 not crawling url with querystring params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514441/nutch-1-9-not-crawling-url-with-querystring-params)

Answer (score 2):

See my previous question here [Adding URL parameter to Nutch/Solr index and search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495468/adding-url-parameter-to-nutch-solr-index-and-search-results)

The first 'Edit' should answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
#-[?*!@=]
```

You have to comment it or modify it as :

```
# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
-[*!@]
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, crawlers shouldn't crawl links with query strings to avoid spams and fake search engines.