# Nutch URL regex normalization of params and session IDs

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

Using Nutch are there any risks involved (like loops) in crawling URLs that have params like

```
http://something.com?page=index
```

The url-regexfilter ignores such URLs. If I remove this filter, am I potentially overlooking something that could cause trouble?

Comment: That's not a valid URL, so what are you expecting the crawler to do with it?

Comment: The URL is only an example. My question is, can such URLs, that have parameters in them cause infinite looping or any such thing? Is that known to happen? Also, ones with session IDs in them.

Comment: I'm saying that the URL structure you've shown is actually invalid. However, I think that nutch probably removes the query string when crawling, because there are URLs that have tracking information in the query string (e.g. google and yahoo have extremely large tracking strings in the URL). **Update:** nutch does remove the query strings, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045716/nutch-1-2-why-wont-nutch-crawl-url-with-query-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nutch removes the query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045716/nutch-1-2-why-wont-nutch-crawl-url-with-query-strings), so it doesn't have a problem with parsing URLs that have them. The reason query strings are most likely removed is because some websites add tracking information in the query string and it can potentially force "dumber" crawlers to go into an "infinite loop" by repeatedly queuing identical links whose only difference is the tracking info in the query string.

### Update:

It turns out that Nutch allows you to [turn on crawling with query strings](http://osdir.com/ml/nutch-user.lucene.apache.org/2010-01/msg00060.html) by commenting out the appropriate line in crawl_urlfilter.txt and regex-urlfilter.txt to enable crawling of urls that contain a '?' in them.

However, as I mentioned in the comment below: the query strings can contain tracking information and that can potentially cause problems with a crawler's URL-seen test. The first problem is that it would make the URL-seen database too big since there would be a lot of duplicates whose only difference is the tracking information in the query string. The second problem is that it's going to make it much slower to run the URL-seen test, because the database is too big!

So keep that in mind when changing the options on whether or not query strings should be allowed.

Comment: Well I think Nutch is giving up on a lot of pages just to avoid getting trapped with trackers. And any SEOed website would not be doing that for sure.

Comment: @che most crawlers keep a database of URLs that they've already seen (for their URL-seen test). A big part of storing URLs is deduplicating them, so it's not just about avoiding getting stuck in a loop but about storage.

Comment: Thanks @Lirik. Please let me know if you find out more about this. I'll take a good look before I turn this filter off.