# Nutch does not crawl URLs with query string parameters

Tags: java, web-crawler, nutch

I am using Nutch1.9 and trying to crawl using individual commands. as can be seen in the output when going in to the 2nd level generater returned with 0 records.
any one has faced this issue ? i am stuck in here from past 2 days. have searched all possible options.  any leads/helps would be much appreciated.

```
<br>#######  INJECT   ######<br>
Injector: starting at 2015-04-08 17:36:20 <br>
Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb<br>
Injector: urlDir: urls<br>
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.<br>
Injector: overwrite: false<br>
Injector: update: false<br>
Injector: Total number of urls rejected by filters: 0<br>
Injector: Total number of urls after normalization: 1<br>
Injector: Total new urls injected: 1<br>
Injector: finished at 2015-04-08 17:36:21, elapsed: 00:00:01<br>
####  GENERATE  ###<br>
Generator: starting at 2015-04-08 17:36:22<br>
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.<br>
Generator: filtering: true<br>
Generator: normalizing: true<br>
Generator: topN: 100000<br>
Generator: jobtracker is 'local', generating exactly one partition.<br>
Generator: Partitioning selected urls for politeness.<br>
Generator: segment: crawl/segments/20150408173625<br>
Generator: finished at 2015-04-08 17:36:26, elapsed: 00:00:03<br>
crawl/segments/20150408173625<br>
#### FETCH  ####<br>
Fetcher: starting at 2015-04-08 17:36:26<br>
Fetcher: segment: crawl/segments/20150408173625<br>
Using queue mode : byHost<br>
Fetcher: threads: 10<br>
Fetcher: time-out divisor: 2<br>
QueueFeeder finished: total 1 records + hit by time limit :0<br>
Using queue mode : byHost<br>
fetching https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=SmartThings (queue crawl delay=5000ms)<br>
Using queue mode : byHost<br>
Using queue mode : byHost<br>
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available<br>
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1<br>
Using queue mode : byHost<br>
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available<br>
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1<br>
Using queue mode : byHost<br>
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available<br>
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1<br>
Using queue mode : byHost<br>
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available<br>
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1<br>
Using queue mode : byHost<br>
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available<br>
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1<br>
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available<br>
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1<br>
Using queue mode : byHost<br>
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available<br>
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1<br>
Using queue mode : byHost<br>
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available<br>
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1<br>
Using queue mode : byHost<br>
Fetcher: throughput threshold: -1<br>
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available<br>
Fetcher: throughput threshold retries: 5<br>
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=1<br>
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1<br>
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1<br>
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1<br>
-activeThreads=1, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=1<br>
Thread FetcherThread has no more work available<br>
-finishing thread FetcherThread, activeThreads=0<br>
-activeThreads=0, spinWaiting=0, fetchQueues.totalSize=0, fetchQueues.getQueueCount=0<br>
-activeThreads=0<br>
Fetcher: finished at 2015-04-08 17:36:33, elapsed: 00:00:06<br>
#### PARSE ####<br>
ParseSegment: starting at 2015-04-08 17:36:33<br>
ParseSegment: segment: crawl/segments/20150408173625<br>
ParseSegment: finished at 2015-04-08 17:36:35, elapsed: 00:00:01<br>
########   UPDATEDB   ##########<br>
CrawlDb update: starting at 2015-04-08 17:36:36<br>
CrawlDb update: db: crawl/crawldb<br>
CrawlDb update: segments: [crawl/segments/20150408173625]<br>
CrawlDb update: additions allowed: true<br>
CrawlDb update: URL normalizing: false<br>
CrawlDb update: URL filtering: false<br>
CrawlDb update: 404 purging: false<br>
CrawlDb update: Merging segment data into db.<br>
CrawlDb update: finished at 2015-04-08 17:36:37, elapsed: 00:00:01<br>
#####  GENERATE  ######<br>
Generator: starting at 2015-04-08 17:36:38<br>
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.<br>
Generator: filtering: true<br>
Generator: normalizing: true<br>
Generator: topN: 100000<br>
Generator: jobtracker is 'local', generating exactly one partition.<br>
Generator: 0 records selected for fetching, exiting ...<br>
#######   EXTRACT  #########<br>
crawl/segments/20150408173625<br>
#### Segments #####<br>
20150408173625<br>
```

EDIT : 
So i checked with another URL with query params (         http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=988409    ) and it crawled it fine...

so this means that it is specifically not crawling my original url :     https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=SmartThings&ac=true

i have tried crawling urls without querystring for this ifttt domain and nutch crawls it successfully...

i think the issue is with crawling https website with query strings. 
any help regarding this issue ?

Comment: Can you include the command you used to run the crawl. It also helps  to see a sample of your crawl links.

Comment: @ameertawfik echo "#######  INJECT   ######"
bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls
echo "####  GENERATE  ###"
bin/nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments -topN 100000
s1=`ls -d crawl/segments/2* | tail -1`
echo $s1
echo "#### FETCH  ####"
bin/nutch fetch $s1
echo "#### PARSE ####"
bin/nutch parse $s1
echo "########   UPDATEDB   ########"
bin/nutch updatedb crawl/crawldb $s1
echo "#####  GENERATE  ######"
bin/nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments -topN 100000
echo "#######   EXTRACT  #########"
s2=`ls -d crawl/segments/2* | tail -1`
echo $s2
echo "#### Segments #####"
ls crawl/segments/

Comment: i am trying to crawl this url with query params : https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=SmartThings

Comment: what is the use of the file automaton-urlfilter.txt ? i looks to have same kinds of regex filters

Comment: please try to use the crawl script. bin/crawl. It is much better option.

Comment: i already tried that. Please see the edit i did in the question. the main is issue i am facing is with crawling https urls with querystrings. generator is just not parsing these urls. alwaya return with 0 Records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, links with query parameters are ignored or filtered out. To enable crawling urls with parameters go to **conf/regex-urlfilter.txt** and comment the following line by adding # to the beginning of the line.

```
# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.
#-[?*!@=]
```

Comment: i have already tried this option but it did not help. is this the only thing needed to be done ? i will try fresh now to try this option.

Answer (score 0):

Alright i found the solution. It was a mistake at my ends. ifttt domain had filters that particular region that i wanted too crawl through robots.txt

before crawling just check whether or not that site is allowing it self to crawl

by checking robots.txt

like this : https://ifttt.com/robots.txt